# Storing H2o models/MOJO outside the file system

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I'm investigating the possibility of storing MOJOs in cloud storage blobs and/or a database.  I have proof-of-concept code working that saves the MOJO to a file then loads the file and stores to the target (and vice-versa for loading), but I'd like to know if there's any way to skip the file step?  I've looked into python's BytesIO, but since the h2o mojo APIs all require a file-path I don't think I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible using the H2O's REST API. Have a look at `model.download_mojo()` for the reference which gets the model from the backend and then persists it using the `_process_response()` method. You can have a look at `h2o.upload_mojo()` for the uploading part.